# Create Node Screenshots in bulk using selectors in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am searching for a way of creating separate node screenshots for each HTML element that matches a particular CSS or XPath selector in a webpage. I would like them to be separate images saved to my file system. (My current workflow is to screenshot the entire page and then crop each element).

I can't seem to find a way of selecting multiple nodes in the Chrome devtools and invoking the node screenshot menu item.

Nor can I find any way of invoking this function programmatically via JavaScript or on the Chrome extensions API. I also haven't been able to locate any existing Chrome extensions that include this functionality.

I'm interested in anything I might have missed, or any alternatives not mentioned above.